# Printing the rest of a string after the second occurrence of a substring

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the remaining string after finding the second occurrence of another string inside the original.

My code:

```
    def after_second(target, search):
        count = 0
        start = target.find(search)
        while start >=0:
            count +=1
            start +=1
            if count == 2:
                return target[start:]

    print(after_second("11223344554321", "3"))
    print(after_second("heyyoheyhi!", "hey"))
```

This code should be outputting:

44554321

hi!

however I am getting back:

44554321

yyoheyhi!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the sting with a maximum of 2 splits will make the 3rd part contain what you need:

```
"heyyoheyhi!".split("hey",2)[2] --> "hi!"
```

Comment: interesting, I hadn't thought to use the split function. Can you break down for me why the comma 2 is needed?

Comment: The second parameter sets a maximum to the number of splits. So, if you have "hey" a 3rd time in the string, it won't cause an additional split.  So the result of that 2 part split will be ["", "yo","hi!"] and splitting "heyyoheyhi!heybye"will return ["","yo","hi!heybye"] making the 3rd part (index 2) contain the rest of the string not matter what it contains.